# ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location) - from time import clock as tick

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhBhM.png)While coding in flask and python via Vs Code, I encountered the error in the screenshot. My local server is down. I have read in several places that the time.clock () method is no longer used and I do not have any information about the current method. And where will this current method be used?

ERROR :
from time import clock as tick
ImportError: cannot import name 'clock' from 'time' (unknown location)

Answer (score 0):

Due to Deprecation of `clock`
use change `time.clock` by `time.perf_counteror`
or

change `import` statement as `from time import perf_counteror as tick`

Comment: Yes, I read that too. But the problem is, I don't know where to use this method and how to run it. Now I am coding flask with pyhton via VsCode.

Comment: Well, here the definition should be entered according to two conditions. The code section according to the if and else case is as follows. If I write this code in the if section, what will I load in the else section?   ""                                                                             # pick best timer function to expose as "tick" - lifted from timeit module.
#if sys.platform == "win32":
    # On Windows, the best timer is time.clock()
    #from time import clock as tick
#else:
    # On most other platforms the best timer is time.time()
    #from time import time as tick